# experimental analysis vs amortized analysis

Tags: c++, algorithm, analysis, amortized-analysis

I am learning algorithm analysis and I have come across a problem.

**What I Have Done**

I wrote a program that generates 30 binary trees of random size where each node of each tree has random value. Now In order to use amortized analysis I assigned (as required) a rank to each node of the tree as following

" If the rank of a node is r, then the rank of its left child is r −1 and the rank of its right child is r + 1. "

Now to define amortized complexity of each node I converted the following equation into a c++ code

"ai = ti + Φ(Si) − Φ(Si−1)"
, where Si−1 is the state of D just before the ith call begins, and Si is the state of D just after it has ﬁnished.

**What's Remaining**

I have to compare the experimental results to the estimation of the amortized analysis.

I am blind at this part and don't know what to do. Anybody good at it or just push me in the in the right direction. I can't find help anywhere else.

Comment: You explain what you have done, but the problem is not well understood. What problem are you trying to solve? I understand you're doing some analysis, but what are you analyzing?

Comment: @AdiLevin Inorder traversal of the binary search tree. Compare the experimental analysis with estimated amortized analysis